# Rally apps sdk 1 and standard reports

Tags: rally

I'm newbie.  Is there a way to display more than one standard report on a html page? I created release drown component for each chart and display those charts in a div element with the cell of a html table. I want to be able to show these charts as one page outside of rally.  separately the chart works but when I combine them into one html page, only 1 works.

the user is allowed to enter a release and the objectid for that release is passed to the chart display function. see code snippet below:

```
function releaseSelected2(dropdown,eventArgs) {
     var selectedItem=eventArgs.item;  
     var selectedValue = eventArgs.value;
     var releaseObjids2 =  new Array();
     releaseObjids2[1]=selectedItem.ObjectID;         
     displayChart2(releaseObjids2[1]);
} //end event listener for chart1
var ddown2=document.getElementById("ddown2");
var config2 = { label: "Select a release   "   };
var releaseDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.ReleaseDropdown(config2,rallyDataSource);
releaseDropdown.display(ddown2,releaseSelected2);

 function releaseSelected(dropdown,eventArgs) {
 var selectedItem=eventArgs.item;
 var selectedValue = eventArgs.value;
 var releaseObjids =  new Array();
 releaseObjids[1]=selectedItem.ObjectID;          
 displayChart1(releaseObjids[1]);
}
var ddown1=document.getElementById("ddown1");
var config = { label: "Select a release " };
var releaseDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.ReleaseDropdown(config,rallyDataSource);
releaseDropdown.display(ddown1,releaseSelected);

function displayChart1(release) { 
  var config = {
  report: rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport.ReleaseDefectTrend,
  title: 'Blacklight: Release defect trend',
  subtitle: 'subtitle placeholder',
   width : 550,
   height: 500,
   releases: release
};

 var report = new rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport(config);
 var div1=document.getElementById("div1");
 report.display(div1);  

  }
 function displayChart2(release2) {
var config2 = {
report: rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport.ReleaseBurnup,
 title: 'Blacklight: Release burnup',
 subtitle: 'subtitle placeholder',
 width : 550,
 height:500,
 release: release2
};                              
var report2 = new rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport(config2);
var div2=document.getElementById("div2");
report2.display(div2); 
}

//html
.
.
<table border="1">
<tr>
   <th>  </th>
   <th>  </th>
 </tr>
<tr>
<th id="ddown1">  </th>
<th id="ddown2"> </th>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
   <div id="div1"></div>
 </td>
<td> 
  <div id="div2"></div>
 </td>
</tr>

</table>
.
.
.
```

Comment: Can you update your code snippet to include more of your app code?  It should definitely be possible to have multiple standard reports in one app.

Comment: @KyleMorse - more of the app code was added. I've included the second release dropdown ui,display chart function and the html placeholder to show both charts. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged the code snippets you gave me and I am able to view both charts now.  Your code seemed to generally work fine for me, so I wonder if the issue was with the table layout you originally had...  Does it work for you?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!-- Copyright (c) 2011  Rally Software Development Corp.  All rights reserved -->
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/1.32/sdk.js?debug=true"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onLoad() {
        var rallyDataSource = new  rally.sdk.data.RallyDataSource("__WORKSPACE_OID__",
             "__PROJECT_OID__",
             "__PROJECT_SCOPING_UP__",
             "__PROJECT_SCOPING_DOWN__");
        var ddown1=document.getElementById("ddown1");
        var config = { label: "Select a release " };
        var releaseDropdown = new rally.sdk.ui.ReleaseDropdown(config,rallyDataSource);
        releaseDropdown.display(ddown1,releaseSelected);

        var ddown2=document.getElementById("ddown2");
        var config2 = { label: "Select a release   "   };
        var releaseDropdown = new                 rally.sdk.ui.ReleaseDropdown(config2,rallyDataSource);
        releaseDropdown.display(ddown2,releaseSelected2);
    }

    function releaseSelected2(dropdown,eventArgs) {
        var selectedItem=eventArgs.item;  
        var selectedValue = eventArgs.value;
        var releaseObjids2 =  new Array();
        releaseObjids2[1]=selectedItem.ObjectID;         
        displayChart2(releaseObjids2[1]);
    } //end event listener for chart1

    function releaseSelected(dropdown,eventArgs) {
        var selectedItem=eventArgs.item;
        var selectedValue = eventArgs.value;
        var releaseObjids =  new Array();
        releaseObjids[1]=selectedItem.ObjectID;          
        displayChart1(releaseObjids[1]);
    }

    function displayChart1(release) { 
        var config = {
            report: rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport.ReleaseDefectTrend,
            title: 'Blacklight: Release defect trend',
            subtitle: 'subtitle placeholder',
            width : 550,
            height: 500,
            releases: release
        };

        var report = new rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport(config);
        var div1=document.getElementById("div1");
        report.display(div1);  
   }

   function displayChart2(release2) {
       var config2 = {
           report: rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport.ReleaseBurnup,
           title: 'Blacklight: Release burnup',
           subtitle: 'subtitle placeholder',
           width : 550,
           height:500,
           releases: release2
       };                              

       var report2 = new rally.sdk.ui.StandardReport(config2);
       var div2=document.getElementById("div2");
       report2.display(div2); 
   }

    rally.addOnLoad(onLoad);
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <td align="center"><div id="ddown1"></div></td>
 <td align="center"><div id="ddown2"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><div id="div1"></div></td>
 <td><div id="div2"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Comment: I copied your modified code and ran it in Rally.  both charts displayed properly with drop downs. the problem is the Release Burnup charts is not updating using values that I select from the drop down. the result is the same in and outside of Rally. It retains some default Release no matter what I select from the droupdown ui. I appreciate your feedback Kyle.

Comment: You're right- the culprit was a typo in the displayChart2 function.  In your config2 you had release instead of releases.  I fixed the code above and it should work now.

Comment: wow!!  Thanks Kyle.  spent hours reviewing and could not find the mistake. thanks again.